# How to check that wifi is NOT connected on android

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi

Ive written some code in an app to check if the phone has a wifi connection, I can do this fine and it works but what I actually want to check for is when the phone is not connected to wifi but it doesn't seem to be working. I think I must have the syntax wrong somewhere. please see code below:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)
getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
myWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if (!myWifi.isConnected()){
        //do something         
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean not working? Returns an error, does nothing - what?

Comment: sorry, it just doesn't seem to check the wifi at all. It carries out the code within the if statement whether there's a wifi connection or not

Comment: its as if the ! is not working. I thought that ! might not be the corrent syntax for this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Using the `getActiveNetworkInfo()` method, use this method:

```
private boolean notConnectedToWifi(){
    final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager).getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected() && activeNetwork.getType() != ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

All you have to do next is to call the method in your condition. Example

```
if(notConnectedToWifi){
 // Oops! You're not connected to wifi!
}
```

Note that I check if `activeNetwork` is connected via `activeNetwork.isConnected()` so if the device is connected to a mobile network, the method `notConnectedToWifi()` will return false. It will also return false if it isn't connected to any network.

Answer (score 0):

try this

/* Network check */

```
public static boolean haveNetworkConnection(Context context) {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }



    if (haveNetworkConnection(youractivityname.this)) {

     //do your work here ..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use BroadcastReciever for getting updates of wifi connectivity in your activity. Below is the sample code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo wifi = connectionManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Is Wifi connected : "+wifi.isConnected(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //  initViews();

        MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
    }
}
```

Also write `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` permission in *AndroidManifest.xml* file

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html), you will get the network info based on  trace whether *WIFI* is connected or not.

Check below code (pass Activity context):

```
public boolean IsInternetConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo nInfo = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nInfo != null) {
            //do your thing
            if (nInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                // connected to wifi
                return true;
            } 

        }
        return false;

    }
    return false;
}
```